# How do I use a variable from a class in another class in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new here so if there is any mistake, please tell me so I can improve. I just finished the Chess Engine tutorial made by Eddie Sharick (I will leave the link below), and now I want to improve it. But the problem is that I want to use a variable from a class in another class but still keep it updated and not a constant. Here's my code:

```
class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inCheck = False
        self.checkMate = False

class Move():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inCheck = ?
        self.checkMate = ?

    def __str__(self):
        # I will use those 2 variables above here...
```

I want to use the self.inCheck and self.checkMate variable in the GameState() class in the **str**() function in the Move() class and keep it updated. Thanks in advance!
Here's the link to Eddie Sharick's Chess Engine Series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBwF487qi8MGU81nDGaeNE1EnNEPYWKY_

Comment: perhaps you're looking for [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) ([Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html))? otherwise when you have an instance of a class `a = Foo()`, you can reference its properties directly, such as `a.bar`

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Think about it: There might be multiple instances of the `GameState` class, each with their own attributes (`inCheck` and `checkMate`). Which ones do you want to use?

Comment: I think maybe you need https://refactoringguru.com/design-patterns/observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be in create a global instance of GameState and then pass it to classes that need to know the current state. Something like:

```
class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inCheck = False
        self.checkMate = False

class Move():
    def __init__(self, game_state: GameState):
        self.game_state = game_state
        self.inCheck = game_state.inCheck
        self.checkMate = game_state.checkMate

class AvailableMoves:
    def __init__(self, game_state: GameState):
        self.game_state = game_state

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gs = GameState()
    m = Move(gs)
    am = AvailableMoves(gs)
    print(m.inCheck)                # prints False
    m.game_state.inCheck = True
    print(gs.inCheck)               # prints True
    print(am.game_state.inCheck)    # prints True
```

This way now Move class is aware of the current game state but is using not its own but a global instance of the GameState class. Now when you make a move and you have a check for example, you can update the instance variables of GameState from inside Move class.

And these updated values will be available to other classes like AvailableMoves that I added.

Comment: You don't call `Move` class from inside `GameState` since the latter doesn't know anything about the former. It's other way around - you can access and change instance attributes of GameState from Move class. I really don't know what you want to put there. I feel like you have Move written like a class but in fact you are trying to use it like a function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I want to call the Move class inside the GameState class, what should I add for the game_state variable? Because I'm getting error like this: ```TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'game_state'``` Sorry bcuz I'm new to OOP.

Comment: If you want to do it like this then why not just have a `move()` method inside `GameState` class. This makes things easier.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem. What I did was `Move(game_state=GameState())`.